# Nuxt.js/Netlify: Index.html is not being creating during build on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a site deployed on Netlify and it's built with Vue/Nuxt. I'm running `yarn run generate` to build and the site *was* working, but at some point the build stopped including my index.html file which now leaves my site with the notorious "Page Not Found". The deploy is running successfully and everything seems as it should except when I download the deploy my index.html is missing. I've seen similar questions, but nothing that answers this specifically.

Comment: Have you ensured your build directory is still 'dist'?

Comment: It's set as such in Netlify